# How to access the data when using expandable rows in primeng's datatable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

When using primeng there's the following method to expand a row. I want to access the selected row's data to send a call to the server and expand the row when the data returns.

According to documentation, there's this `(onRowClick)="dt.toggleRow($event.data)"` call back, and the data is accessible using angular's double bracket notation `{{id}}`.  However, how would I access the data from the selected row in typescript and not in html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking is how do you access the data from the `onRowClick` method?

If that is what you are wanting to know, I think that if you defined your `onRowClick` event call like this:

```
(onRowClick)="dt.toggleRow($event.data); rowClicked($event.data)"
```

you will then have access to the data of the row clicked in your `rowClicked` method.